# how to spoof Ip in side the masge with syslog-ng

Tags: centos, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

So I have been asked to do this strange task:

we have a central logger that reserve logs from different hosts
this central logger will send all logs to another relay.

the task is to spoof the actual host IP for the sender from the relay to another host :)

do you have any ideas

Br.

Answer (score 0):

syslog-ng can do this if you use UDP to transfer the messages, see the [spoof-source](https://syslog-ng.com/documents/html/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-destination-network-chapter.html) option.